# select from three table

Tags: sql, select, foreign-keys

i have three table Product, MapCatProduct, Category.

Table definitions:

Table 1: Product

```
Column 1: int ProductID (PK)
Column 2: nvarchar(255) Name
```

Table 2: MapCatProduct

```
Column 1: int MapCatProductID (PK)
Column 2: int ProductID(FK)
Column 3: int CategoryID(FK)
```

Mapping table: Category

```
Column 1: int CategoryID (PK)
Column 2: nvarchar(255) Name
```

I want select Product table when ProductID is input Parameter and categoryID this parameters Equals all results.

for eaxample:
(InputParameters) ProductID = 14

results:

ProductID = 14
CategoryID = **2**

ProductID = 34
CategoryID = **2**

ProductID = 63
CategoryID = **2**

**notice:
it is possible that one productID have 'n' CategoryID**

My Code is:

```
SELECT p.Id,p.Name FROM Product p 
WHERE p.Id = @Id --input parameter
UNION
(SELECT TOP 5 p.Id,p.Name FROM Product p
INNER JOIN MapCatProduct mcp
ON p.Id = mcp.ProductId
INNER JOIN Category c
ON c.Id = mcp.CategoryId)
```

Comment: Have a look for some info on SQL `JOIN`s... Try [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: hi @gbn . i want use union but not work.
select product table and union joined select two table(MapCatProduct,Category).

Comment: @Awatt The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns from two or more tables. Would you please show us a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first change the types of those foreign keys to the same type as used in the foreign table.  In this case INT.
No need to use a large nvarchar for a column that only keeps integers.

After that you can just join the map table to the other 2 tables.
For example:

```
select 
 prod.ProductID, cat.CategoryID, 
 prod.Name as ProductName, cat.Name as CategoryName
from MapCatProduct map
join Product prod on prod.ProductID = map.ProductID
join Category cat on cat.CategoryID = map.CategoryID
where map.CategoryID in (
   select distinct CategoryID 
   from MapCatProduct
   where ProductID = @ProductId 
)
```

But of course, if you only need the id's, then selecting only from the map table is sufficient.

```
select ProductID, CategoryID
from MapCatProduct
where CategoryID in (
   select distinct CategoryID 
   from MapCatProduct
   where ProductID = @ProductId 
)
```

Comment: thanks @LukStorm. this worked!
"type foreign keys a mistake was written that edited."

Answer (score 0):

You want all `ProductID` in the same category on the input `ProductID`?

```
SELECT ProductID, CategoryID
FROM MapCatProductID
WHERE CategoryID = 
(SELECT DISTINCT CategoryID
FROM MapCatProductID
WHERE ProductID = <input Param>)
```